# What procedural extension does Teradata SQL Assistant use?

Tags: sql, teradata

What Procedural Extension does Teradata SQL Assistant use? I understand that you are able to connect to different types of databases (Microsoft SQL, Teradata, Oracle) via OBDC connection. Does it adopt the Procedural extension to which ever database it is connected to?

Comment: Thats the data discovery program...no?  It uses teradataSQL or the language of the ODBC connection it's using.

Comment: @Twelfth , Which one does it use? How is it able to use either or?

Comment: repeat myself.   It uses teradataSQL or the language of the ODBC connection it's using.  It can use either, that's basically the core functionality of it.

Comment: Well if you imply that, we could just say "it adopts the language depending on ODBC connection". Thanks alot.

Comment: more elegant than my wording.  It's a challenge pretty much any data investigator or ETL tool needs to get around eventually.